# Replace text between all the strings

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have multiple strings and I want to change the string which is between first and the last string.

The middle string is dynamic and it changes but the first and the last string remains the same.

For example this is the string,

Please note that this is the entire string.

%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%22%7D%2C%22
%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY%22%7D%2C%22
%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ%22%7D%2C%22

So is there any function which can find all the middle string which has the same first and the last string ?

I tried this function,

```
private function replace_between($str, $needle_start, $needle_end, $replacement)
    {
    
        $pos = strpos($str, $needle_start);

        $start = $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + strlen($needle_start);
    
        $pos = strpos($str, $needle_end, $start);
        $end = $pos === false ? strlen($str) : $pos;
    
        return substr_replace($str, $replacement, $start, $end - $start);
    }
```

This function only replaces the first occurrence. I want to change all the occurrences.

`Output of this function`

```
%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22REPLACED___TEXT%22%7D%2C%22
%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY%22%7D%2C%22
%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ%22%7D%2C%22
```

It is doesn't change the other middle strings.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide example of how you call the `replace_between()`

Comment: if the strings are separated by a space (looks like so in the example provided), you could `explode` it using the space as a separator. The second element of the exploded array should give the second string..

Comment: @ariefbayu eplace_between(ORIGINAL_STRING,"%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%","%22%7D%2C%22","REPLACETEXT") This replaces the first occurrence but all other occurrences doest change

Comment: @user3532758 What are you talking about ? I didn't get it. I want to replace the string between 2 strings. Why would I explode it ?

Comment: so, suppose you have 3 lines of those, you want to replace EVERYTHING in between those 3 lines, with only one ""REPLACE TEXT"? I mean, all three lines will have the same content. @AbhishekDeshkar

Comment: @ariefbayu Those are not 3 lines. It is the entire string. I have wrote it in a separate line. First and last occurrence  remains the same. I have edited the question, please have a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for that:

```
<?php
// Your code here!
$string = "%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%22%7D%2C%22 %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY%22%7D%2C%22 %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ%22%7D%2C%22";

$replaceInto = "---REPLACED---";
$pattern = '/\%22\%3A\%7B\%22id\%22\%3A\%22(.*)\%22\%7D\%2C\%22/U';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, "%22%3A%7B%22id%22\%3A%$replaceInto%22%7D%2C%22", $string);

var_dump($result);
```

> Notice that I used suffix `U` in the `$pattern`. This is called ['Nongreedy'](https://medium.com/@wpcarro/non-greedy-regular-expressions-7dfb5177d57e) modifier.

It would result in the following:

> string(176) "%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%---REPLACED---%22%7D%2C%22 %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%---REPLACED---%22%7D%2C%22 %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%---REPLACED---%22%7D%2C%22"

Here is the online test on [Paiza.IO](https://paiza.io/projects/TMbZ2JVuC1mPqnqLve5e-w).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. However there is a change here, it should be like this.

preg_replace($pattern,"%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22$replaceInto%22%7D%2C%22", $string);

Answer (score 1):

> @user3532758 What are you talking about ? I didn't get it. I want to
> replace the string between 2 strings. Why would I explode it ?

```
$string = "%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%22%7D%2C%22 %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY%22%7D%2C%22 %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ%22%7D%2C%22";

$exploded = explode(" ", $string);

$exploded[1] = "replaced string";

echo implode($exploded, " ");

// result: %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%22%7D%2C%22 replaced string %22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ%22%7D%2C%22
```

Comment: Why did you add the space ? I have edited the question. Please look into it again.